How to load a secret as a volume using helm?
I am new in kubernetes and helm.
I have loaded the keystore.jks file as a secret:
kubectl create secret generic starburst-keystore --from-file=keystore.jks

Now I want to mount in my container that secret as a file so I made this yaml to be use by helm
$ cat test.yaml
coordinator:
  envFrom:
  - secretRef:
      name: environment-vars

  additionalProperties: |
    log.path=/tmp/starburst/log/server.log
    starburst.data-product.enabled=${ENV:data_products_enabled}
    data-product.starburst-jdbc-url=${ENV:data_products_jdbc_url}
    data-product.starburst-user=${ENV:data_products_username}
    data-product.starburst-password=${ENV:data_products_password}
    query.max-memory=1PB
    starburst.access-control.enabled=${ENV:starburst_access_control_enabled}
    starburst.access-control.authorized-users=${ENV:starburst_access_control_authorized_users}
  etcFiles:
    properties:
      config.properties: |
        coordinator=true
        node-scheduler.include-coordinator=false
        http-server.http.port=8080
        ...
        web-ui.enabled=true
        http-server.process-forwarded=true
        insights.persistence-enabled=true
        insights.metrics-persistence-enabled=true
        insights.jdbc.url=${ENV:database_connection_url}
        insights.jdbc.user=${ENV:database_username}
        insights.jdbc.password=${ENV:database_password}
        starburst.data-product.enabled=true
      password-authenticator.properties: |
        password-authenticator.name=file
      log.properties: |
        io.trino.plugin.iceberg=INFO
  nodeSelector:
    starburstpool: base
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 2
      memory: 12Gi
    requests:
      cpu: 2
      memory: 12Gi
  volumes:
  - name: keystore-volume
    secret:
      secretName: starburst-keystore
  volumeMounts:
  - name: keystore-volume
    mountPath: "/opt/starburst/keystore"
    readOnly: true

Then I use helm to loaded
helm upgrade starburst-enterprise starburstdata/starburst-enterprise --install --values test.yaml

But when I check the volumen in the pod, the path don't exist
$ kubectl exec -it coordinator-75b946648c-p9bp9 -- sh -c "ls -R /opt"
Defaulted container "coordinator" out of: coordinator, starburst-enterprise-init (init)
/opt:

The yaml file is from https://github.com/starburstdata/starburst-deploy/blob/main/helm/starburst-with-biac/starburst.yaml
In that file you can see all the conf but I want to add the keystore.jks inside de pod

What you've included in the test.yaml file is just the configuration; the Helm chart could do pretty much anything with that configuration.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]; on the one hand, include the actual template code that's  creating the Deployment (and presumably consuming .Values.coordinator.envFrom), and on the other, remove the configuration properties that don't matter?
